# variable in javascript change css property

Tags: javascript

Ive been at this for hours but I cannot find out what is wrong here. I think its the variable "url" but not sure how to fix it or how to go about this.

here is my code:

```
function changebackground() {
    let randombackground     = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
    let fullnameofbackground = randombackground + ".jpg";
    let finalname            = fullnameofbackground.toString();
    let url                  = '../bulkbackgrounds/' + finalname;
    console.log(url)

    document.getElementById("body-background").style.backgroundImage = 'url(url)';
}
```

Comment: Please try like this:
`const elemet = document.getElementById("body-background");` after then `element.style.backgroundImage = url;`

Comment: `'url(url)'` is literally that. You should use `\`url(${url})\`` to instantiate the `url` variable into the string

Answer (score 3):

You have to use back ticks and expressions if you want use string template literals

```
document.getElementById("body-background").style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
```